# Python: Bundle python program for windows of other architecture

Tags: python, pyinstaller

So.. i have a Windows x86 machine on which i make software..
but when i use pyinstaller it becomes only x86 software..

how may i make the .exe for windows x64 too?
any other pyinstaller alternative?

(i am trying to make my Media player a exe for windows both architecture)

I have searched the whole internet but i can't find a good answer...

```
SPECS: (if you need)
OS: Windows 7 SP1 (just do not ask why windows 7)
Python: 3.8.10
Arch: x86 (do i need to tell that?)
```

Comment: Your 32-bit executable will run perfectly fine on a 64-bit Windows machine.

Comment: @TimRoberts oh really? if you have x64 then try running [this file](http://whirlpool-programmer.github.io/checking_x64.exe)..

Comment: Oh really?  Windows Defender says you tried to get me to execute a Trojan.  32-bit Windows applications work just fine on 64-bit Windows.  They always have.

Comment: @TimRoberts i hate windows defender btw.. but the script for that file just had `import time print("something") time.sleep(10000)`

Comment: @TimRoberts if that's the case (x86 python files run on x64) then thanks..